# place text starting at the top right corner of image

Tags: html, css

How can I place text starting at the top right corner of an image?

**html**

```
<div class="img-text">
   <img>
</div>
<div class="div">
   <h4>Title</h4>
   <ul>
      <li>Image Caption</li>
      <li>Added on which date</li>
      <li>Description of the image?</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.img-text img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px
}
```

Comment: why don't you use a div with your image as background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `display:inline-block` to get both the `div` and the `img` on the same line.

```
.img-text, .div {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/atezip/3/edit)**

Answer (score 3):

Add your image and text to a common container with relative positioning and then absolutely position the text to the right. For example:

```
.container {
position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.container img {
    position: absolute;
}

.img-text{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/sJEKE/

Answer (score 0):

This is so convoluted. Instead, just use classes like

```
.text-wrap-right {
    float: right;
margin: 10px;
}
.text-wrap-left {
    float: left;
margin: 10px;
}
```

and put them on your image

```html
<style>
  .text-wrap-right {
    float: right;
margin: 10px;
}
.text-wrap-left {
    float: left;
margin: 10px;
}
  </style>
<div > <img src="http://a.lgorithms.com/mobile/ArtStarModel.png" width="40%" alt="ArtStar Model" class="text-wrap-left" > 
     ArtStar is an "App Toy": a platform for art-related games and apps. 
        A.lgorithms created 2 games and a cross-platform app for ArtStar. In <a href="screenshots/TraceStar.png" class="thickbox" title='<img src="screenshots/TraceStar.png" width="300px" border="1" />'><strong>TraceStar</strong></a>,
        we developed a game in which the player, looking through the device, sees ArtStar drawing board and traces a drawing to
        get a good score - and make the drawing come alive. The game uses image recognition algorithms we developed in-house and some
        heavy duty video technologies. Click here 
        to see a video.
        
        </div>
```